# dropping column in one dataframe is dropping in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I create a dataframe 2 based on another dataframe 1.
When I drop a column on dataframe 2, it also drops column on dataframe 1.
This seems wrong but maybe I don't understand what's supposed to happen here.

[image]

I expect the two dataframes to be independent of each other after df2 = df1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can pandas DataFrames change each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35665135/why-can-pandas-dataframes-change-each-other)

Comment: `df2 = df1.copy()`

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it).

Comment: For future reference, please see [ask], which specifically says *not* to use screenshots of code/data/errors.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you! Should I delete the question or just edit it to remove screenshot?

Comment: Probably delete since it's a duplicate.